# How to generate dummy data like covid cases using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I want to generate a random data with variable rate of increment not fixed one so that it resemble to real world.
[image: required random data distribution]

Thanks in advance

I am not able to get a distribution like above

Comment: You could simulate that by multiplying by a since wave, `abs(sin(N*pi/2)`.

Comment: The distribution from the image look like 2 Gaussian's. This also can help you to create similar toy dataset.

Comment: One possibility would be to simulate the trajectory of the disease, as described in this [paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc15papers/012.pdf), which describes implementation of a stochastic event-based [SEIR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology). You would need to parameterize it to correspond to the disease you want to model and the efficacy and timing of any interventions undertaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generating concise data on such a sensitive topic is not easy. I answer this question with a purely demonstrative example, but I would refer you to **reading scientific publications that explain well the underlying statistical criteria behind such studies**.*

*A good approach would be to train a machine learning model on real pandemic data and then have it produce time-series forecasting.*

---

If we want to construct a **toy dataset**, based on what we have been able to learn about the covid, we can make it resemble a Gaussian trend with arbitrary peaks. We can use [numpy.random.normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) to generate this data.

Some parameters must be mandatorily set:

1. Number of days on which to generate data.
2. Maximum value that can reach a peak (we don't want to get 10 billion contagions!).
3. Number of peaks (optionally).

The example I give is really very simple, but I think it can represent the unpredictability we experienced during this pandemic, so as to meet the "variable rate of increment not fixed" requirement.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import random

base = datetime.datetime.today()

numdays = 100
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]

num_of_peaks = 5
max_of_peak = 5000
peaks = [random.randint(0, max_of_peak) for x in range(num_of_peaks)]

all_data = []
for p in peaks:
    all_data.extend(np.random.normal(p, p//10, size=numdays//num_of_peaks))

print(all_data)
plt.plot(date_list, all_data)
plt.show()
```

Below are 3 images of possible results generated almost completely randomly:
[image]
[image]
[image]

It may make sense to intervene on the parameters I put in by hand to smooth out the Gaussians a bit more and get a more sinus-like pattern. But again, this is a completely toy dataset.